# Using StringSets Amazon DynamoDB Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an android application which uses Amazon DynamoDB. My table of users look like this:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = Const.TEST_TABLE_NAME)
public static class User {
    private int userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "userID")
    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

And everything works fine. My question is, if I have a string set in my table how can I insert it to my code? Using `String[]` doesn't work( I've tried adding:

```
    private String[] favourites;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "favourites")
    public String[] getFavourites() {
        return favourites;
    }

    public void setFavourites(String[] favourites) {
        this.favourites = favourites;
    }
```

) but it keeps throwing errors. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a `Set` of `String`. If you are using the default `ConversionScheme` as part of your `DynamoDBMapperConfig` (which if you don't specify your own configuration, the default is used), all you need to do is change your type to Java's `Set<String>` and the mapper will marshall it appropriately.

```
private Set<String> favourites;

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "favourites")
public Set<String> getFavourites() {
    return favourites;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is going to help. Works for me.

```
private List<String> favourites;

....

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "favourites")
public List<String> getFavourites() {
    return favourites;
}

public void setFavourites(List<String> favourites) {
    this.favourites = favourites;
}
```